Side notes in one paragraph
I'm looking for solutions to typeset margin/side notes

vertically in a marginpar starting from the bottom next to the main text body, similar to what was achieved here, and
capable of handling multiple notes from the same page to appear in the same paragraph in marginpar, similar to what is achieved in footmisc or manyfoot with [para] option, as shown in the picture below, in which three side notes are in the same paragraph.

Ideally I'd like to have the notes go on into the next page if the margin is full. But I'm happy to manually inserting \newpage for the time being.

Below is a minimal compilable test file in which I want to move the footnotes to the right margin, and rotate 90 degrees anticlockwise.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[para*]{manyfoot} 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[arabic]

\newcommand{\mynote}[1]{% to be redefined 
    \FootnotetextA{}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
Lorem\mynote{note 1} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit\mynote{note 2}. Aliquam gravida nec nulla sit amet 
rutrum\mynote{note 3}.
\end{document}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

edited to add the test file

From a readers point of view you'd have lost me, i.e. I'd put your document aside + away. I suggest coming up with a better visual concept. E.g. if you look into O'Reilly's books they have all sorts of visually formatted inserts with explained meanings. Have a look at package tcolorbox to mimick some of those.
